# Compare column labels of pivot table in conditional formatting

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have pivot table with below data in excel 2016. I need to apply conditional formatting using formula, when data is between 10 to 25 and Year is 2011 or 2015, then make backgound of data to red.

I am able to to do till first condition but as soon as I apply condition for checking year, it breaks.

```
=AND(Year="2011",OR(Amount > 10,Amount<25))
```

It should paint background red only if year ={2011,2015} and amount ranging between 10 to 25.

[image]

Comment: I am using conditional formatting option in excel.

Comment: =AND(OR(Year="2011",Year="2015"),Amount>10,Amount<25).

Comment: 2011 2012 2013 2014
ABC A1 12  12 12 12
DEF A1 23 27 23 77
PQR A3 45 28 45 45
XYZ A2 65 33 45 90
LMN A2 23 53 23 26
STU S1 11 28 49 28

Comment: @BigBen - Thaks for quick reply. Is there a way where I could declare Year values in signle go ? In my actual code i need to compare around 20 values. Somethiing like Year ={ 2011,2019,2018,1027,1991,2001} ?

Comment: use a lookup table maybe. Also note that you've changed the requirements of your original question :)

Comment: Also for amounts I can specify single cell and apply that over all pivot table. But how can I specify the dimension value ? i.e. if my first value starts at E5 being year 2011 and its value at E6? It's coming as white background.

Comment: Can you maybe add a screenshot with sample data and the expected result to your question? That would make this easier to understand and hopefully answer.

Comment: Yeah. I thought it would still be applicable to my case but now i sense its more complex :). BTW my formula is now =AND(E5="040",C7 < -1000000000, C7 > 1000000000)

Comment: added screenshot. So how can I specify years like 2011,2007,2009 ? Do i need to manully put OR condition mentioning every cell they belong to?